# What sort of GDC pass (if any) is best for a cash-strapped indie?

Tags: business

I'm doing a web game startup with one other person. We support ourselves with contract programming. I'm considering attending GDC for the first time, but we're really tight on cash. Money spent on passes and plane tickets slows our startup's growth.

Some say GDC is a good way to meet clients, but fortunately we have plenty of client interest, so I don't consider that a major concern. Still, it's generally good to network, and it's healthy for us as designers and developers to learn from the rest of the community.

Which type of pass should we invest in?

Answer (score 4):

Likely the cheapest pass you can find that gets you in. Also, purchase early (before Feb 2). Looks like the Expo pass would suit you since you're not sure what to expect: **$195**.

> **Expo Pass**
>
> This pass is good for people interested in an introductory
> look at all the GDC has to offer.

Or if you're more interested in the Independent games summit: **$325**

> **Independent Games Summit Pass**
>
> This pass is good for people interested in attending the Independent
> Games Summit. The Independent Games Summit Pass is available on a
> limited basis.

Break down of all the passes offered:
http://www.gdconf.com/attend/passes.html

Comment: Note that the Expo pass doesn't get you into any talks at all except for 5 sample talks that may be full to capacity. You get access to the show floor, the Game Career Seminar, and the awards show.

Comment: Yep, limited experience for a limited price. What's the best pass for people with little money who aren't really concerned with the event? The cheapest.